# Workings of ``const Mat* samples`` param in OpenCV's ``calcCovarMatrix`` function?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to calculate the covariance matrix of multiple Matrices in OpenCV and saw 2 versions of [`calcCovarMatrix`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=calccovarmatrix#void%20calcCovarMatrix(const%20Mat*%20samples,%20int%20nsamples,%20Mat&%20covar,%20Mat&%20mean,%20int%20flags,%20int%20ctype)). I got curious and wanted to use the overloaded version which takes `const Mat* samples, int nsamples` as first 2 params.

The question: what is the `samples` param? Is it a pointer to the first item of a vector of Mats? Why is it not a vector itself? What does one pass into it/how does the param work?

P.S.: I do NOT want to use the other overloaded version of the function! I want to understand the actual code used in the version I asked about.

Comment: Why don't you check the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8bde6aea4ba19454554aa008922d967b552e79cc/modules/core/src/matmul.dispatch.cpp#L663) then?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear to me whether I got your question right but I try: Imagine you have a function which takes `std::vector<SomeThing>` (of course, at best with `const std::vector<SomeThing>&`). Now, imagine you have a constant static array of `SomeThings` which you want to feed in - not possible without a copy which might be as expensive as unnecessary. Now, imagine the opposite: a function which takes a `const SomeThing*` together with a `size_t`. Yeah, it looks ugly and C-stylish BUT: you can feed in the array by address and it's length by a little `sizeof` magic.

Comment: ...You can also feed in a `std::vector` by using `std::vector::data()` and `std::vector::size()`. (This works for all types except `bool` but that's another story.) Hence, the ugly C-stylish function is actually more flexible. Btw. if in doubt just make a second function (as inline) which takes a `std::vector` and calls the other with `data()` and `size()`. (If I hit your issue I would enjoy to make this as an answer with a minimal practical example.) ;-)

Comment: @Miki , because the source code only shows WHAT is being done, not WHY it is what it is (i.e. doesn't explain why it's not a ``std::vector``).

Comment: @Scheff so it's for flexibility? Thanks for the explanation! I'll gladly accept your answer if you make one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm convinced that the authors of OpenCV preferred the `const Mat*`, `int` pair of arguments over a `std::vector` because this is more flexible.

Imagine a function which has to process a series of certain objects.

In C++, a series of objects can be stored with a `std::vector`. But what if the series of that objects is static const i.e. can be defined at compile time? A plain old C array of that objects might do the job as well.

A function which can process such a series of objects could accept a `const std::vector&`. If applied to a C array, a temporary vector instance had to be build. The C++ code is relatively simple but it leaves a queasy feeling in the stomache because the array contents has to be copied into the temporary `std::vector` instance just to pass it to the function.

The opposite case: the function accepts a pointer to start object and a count (like usual in C). Such a function can be applied to C arrays as well as to `std::vector` because `std::vector` provide a [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) method which provides a const pointer to its first element and a `size()` method. Furthermore, it is granted that the vector elements are stored consecutively like in a C array.

So, my simple example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Pi (from Windows 7 calculator)
const float Pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

struct Point {
  float x, y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Point &point)
{
  return out << '(' << point.x << ", " << point.y << ')';
}

Point average(const Point *points, size_t size)
{
  assert(size > 0);
  Point sum = points[0];
  for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    sum.x += points[i].x; sum.y += points[i].y;
  }
  return { sum.x / (unsigned)size, sum.y / (unsigned)size };
}

static const Point square[] = {
  { -0.5f, -0.5f },
  { +0.5f, -0.5f },
  { +0.5f, +0.5f },
  { -0.5f, +0.5f }
};
static const size_t sizeSquare = sizeof square / sizeof *square;

int main()
{
  // process points of a static const square (using average() with an array)
  std::cout << "CoG of " << sizeSquare << " points of square: "
    << average(square, sizeSquare) << '\n';
  // build a tesselated circle
  std::vector<Point> circle;
  const unsigned n = 16;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    const float angle = i * 2 * Pi / n;
    circle.push_back({ std::sin(angle), std::cos(angle) });
  }
  // process points of that circle (using average() with a vector)
  std::cout << "CoG of " << circle.size() << " points of circle: "
    << average(circle.data(), circle.size()) << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
CoG of 4 points of square: (0, 0)
CoG of 16 points of circle: (-5.58794e-09, 4.47035e-08)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c1c40891baa2bec)</kbd>

For convenience, the following alternative definition could be added for `std::vector`:

```
static inline Point average(const std::vector<Point> &points)
{
  return average(points.data(), points.size());
}
```

A generic solution would provide instead an alternative with two iterators which could be applied to any container. (The C++ standard library is ful of examples for this.)

I can only assume that the OpenCV authors focused on performance rather than on flexibility (but that's only my personal guess).